# Python : Issue is checking os.path.exists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to check if a particular directory path exists or not.

below is my code

```
temp_path = '\\diwali\NSID-HYD-01\college'
meta_path = os.path.realpath(temp_path)
print(os.path.exists(meta_path))
```

When I am trying to execute this, it is throwing error as below

```
temp_path = '\\diwali\NSID-HYD-01\college'
#          ^
```

error

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 8-9: malformed \N character escape
```

Help me resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

Python interprets backslashes (`\`) inside strings as leading characters for escape codes. For example `\n` is a line-feed character.

If you want it to treat them as simply backslashes, add an `r` before the string, like so:

```
temp_path = r'\\diwali\NSID-HYD-01\college'
```

Comment: I am getting temp_path as a string from UI. How to manage this?

Comment: @AbhishekBajaj Afraid you're SOL.

Comment: You should update your question, then. My guess is that the UI doesn't send you a UTF-8 string but something else that needs to be encoded in UTF-8 before it can't be sent to the file system.

Comment: Looks like it the issue of \N. There exist \N in my temp_path variable. Because of which this issue is occurring. How to resolve such cases

Comment: Are you talking about backslash-N or about a life-feed?

Comment: I am talking about \N. in the file_path "\\diwali\NSID-HYD-01\college".
8th character.

Answer (score 0):

another method is using two backslashes `\\` before `N` like this:

```
temp_path = '\\diwali\\NSID-HYD-01\college'
```

If you are get it from UI (as you mentioned in comments) you can replace `\` with `\\`:

```
temp_path = '\\diwali\NSID-HYD-01\college'.replace("\\", "\\\\")
# '\\diwali\\NSID-HYD-01\\college'
```

Comment: You're just replacing single slashes with another single slash. To replace it with two slashes you have to use four backslashes.